# Testing an embedded device processor

Tags: linux, bash, cpu, operating-systems, embedded

I am writing some tests to test the processor on an embedded device (running on Linux). The device shell supports Ash, python and I can even run C code after compilation in scratchbox.

Can you give me some ideas as to what tests I could write to test the processor?

Comment: infinite loops are always fun

Comment: What do you want to test exactly?

Comment: @haimg I want to stress test the CPU. I want to take the CPU utilization to close to 100% for say 10 mins and then stop my test.

Comment: What other kinds of testing I could do? Any ideas would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stress-testing CPU is a bit complicated. If you're just interested in thermal testing, compile something like [this simple C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456786/create-thread-with-70-cpu-utilization), which will load a CPU with infinite loop doing simple math calculation. If you need further help with writing/compiling such a program, you'd better take this to StackOverflow.

However, if you're interested in testing a specific CPU component (ALU, FPU, cache, etc.), then this is much more complicated and requires an intimate knowledge of the architecture/CPU and serious programming skills. You can ask the embedded board vendor, maybe they already have such software. If not, you're pretty much out of luck.